# Getting issue while trying to access internet from private-subnet instance via nat intance in aws?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, nat, subnet, vpc

I create a vpc with two subnets public and private.

In public subnet I used NAT instance for internet access. I trie to access internet which is in private subnet, but failed. I configured well for security groups and route tables. Is it necessary that NAT instance should be of m1.small type?

Answer (score 1):

No nat box can have any instance type. However, in your private subnet's Route table, there should be an entry like this

Destination cidr: 0.0.0.0/0
Target:

If this is already in place, then check the security group. For testing try to open all traffic in all security groups that you have.

Answer (score 0):

there might be chance you have not selected correct NAT instance 
while creating NAT instance  in **Step 1: Choose an Amazon Machine Image (AMI)**
make sure you instance name contain **"nat"** ,

after clicking on **Community AMIs**   and add filter for **nat** , it is not filtering correct name ,
make sure your instance name should contain **"nat"**

below are only nat  Amazon Machine Image (AMI) available in community

- amzn-ami-vpc-**nat**-hvm-2018.03.0.20180811-x86_64-ebs
- amzn-ami-vpc-**nat**-hvm-2017.09.1-testlongids.20180307-x86_64-ebs
- amzn-ami-vpc-**nat**-hvm-2017.09.1.20180103-x86_64-ebs